# Why does output shape in a simple Elman RNN depend on the sequence length(while hidden state shape doesn't)?

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am learning about RNNs, and am trying to code one up using PyTorch.
I have some trouble understanding the output dimensions

Here is some code for a simple RNN architecture

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_dim, n_layers):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim=hidden_dim
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_dim, n_layers, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        r_out, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)

        return r_out, hidden
```

So, what I understand is the hidden_dim is the number blocks I will have in my hidden layer, and essentially the number of features in the output and in the hidden state.

I create some dummy data, to test it

```
test_rnn = RNN(input_size=1, hidden_dim=4, n_layers=1)

# generate evenly spaced, test data pts
time_steps = np.linspace(0, 6, 3)
data = np.sin(time_steps)
data.resize((3, 1))

test_input = torch.Tensor(data).unsqueeze(0) # give it a batch_size of 1 as first dimension
print('Input size: ', test_input.size())

# test out rnn sizes
test_out, test_h = test_rnn(test_input, None)
print('Hidden state size: ', test_h.size())
print('Output size: ', test_out.size())
```

What I get is

```
Input size:  torch.Size([1, 3, 1])
Hidden state size:  torch.Size([1, 1, 4])
Output size:  torch.Size([1, 3, 4])
```

So I understand that the shape of x is determined like so
`x = (batch_size, seq_length, input_size)`.. so 1 bath size, and input of 1 feature and 3 time steps(sequence length).

For hidden state, like so `hidden = (n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim)`.. so I had 1 layer, batch size 1, and 4 blocks in my hidden layer.

What I don't get is the RNN output. From the documentation, `r_out = (batch_size, time_step, hidden_size)`.. Wasn't the output supposed to be the same as the hidden state that was output from the hidden units? That is, if I have 4 units in my hidden layer, I would expect it to output 4 numbers for the hidden state, and 4 numbers for the output. Why is the time step a dimension of the output? Because, each hidden unit, takes in some numbers, outputs a state S and output Y, and both of these are equal, yes? I tried a diagram, this is what I came up with. Help me understand what part of it I'm doing wrong.[image]

So TL;DR 

Why does output shape in a simple Elman RNN depend on the sequence length(while hidden state shape doesn't)? For in the diagram I drew, I see both of them being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PyTorch API, the output is a sequence of hidden states during the RNN computation, i.e., there is one hidden state vector per input vector. The hidden state is the last hidden state, the state the RNN ends with after processing the input, so `test_out[:, -1, :]` = `test_h`.

Vector `y` in your diagrams is the same as a hidden state `Ht`, it indeed has 4 numbers, but the state is different for every time step, so you have 4 number for every time step.

The reason why PyTorch separates the sequence of outputs = hidden states (it's not the same in LSTMs, though) is that you can have a batch of sequences of different lengths. In that case, the final state is not simply `test_out[:, -1, :]`, because you need to select final states based on the lengths of individual sequences.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question at all.
I still don't understand why my diagram is wrong, how it should be corrected and how it is different from what a normal RNN is.

Comment: That's a wonderful edit. It helped understand quite a lot of things. So to confirm my understanding, those 4 numbers y0 through y4, are produced for every time step x0 through x2, and the output produced for timestep x2 also happens to be the hidden state Ht+1, is that correct? And secondly, I'd also like to confirm whether my connections from Ht-1 to Ht are correct in my original diagram, ie they're fully connected like that, right? As well as the connections from X to Ht, fully connected as well, correct?